# How to update related table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel `5.3`.
How to update related table in Laravel?

There are 2 tables,`students` and `hobbies`, they have many-to-many relations.

In view,hobbies are checkboxes,like this:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="1" > basketball
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="2" > football
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="3" > swimming
```

In controller,`store()` method is like this,it can work:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $student=Student::create($request->except('hobby'));
    $student->hobbies()->attach($request->hobby);
    return redirect()->action('StudentController@index');
}
```

`update()` method is like this,hobbies can not be updated:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
    $student->update($request->except('hobby'));

    //How to update hobbies?
    $student->hobbies()->attach($request->hobby);

    return redirect()->action('StudentController@show', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

How to update hobbies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use update. Use the `sync` method:

```
$student->hobbies()->sync($request->hobby);
```

Comment: `$student->hobbies()->attach($request->hobby);`  should be `$student->hobbies()->sync($request->hobby);`? But it also doesn't work.