# How to change value in hasOne related table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I can't figure this out and I know it's so basic ;-)

I have two tables, user and userInfo. The relationship is one-to-one, very simple. How can I update userInfo? This is code from the end of my UserSeeder:

```
// after seeding, change the 1st user to always be the same
$user = User::first();
$user->name = 'admin';
$user->email = 'test@mysite.test';
$user->userInfo()->first()->AccountStatus = 1;
$user->save();
```

It runs without failing but userInfo doesn't set the user's AccountStatus = 1.

What am I missing?!! ;-)

Also: why do I have to do `userInfo()->first()` when there's always only one userInfo record connected to the user?

p.s. this is NOT a duplicate of [How to update related table in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540610/how-to-update-related-table-in-laravel) -- that's for many-to-many relationship... this is one-to-one.

Comment: please provide your model class for user and userInfo, it will be helpful

Comment: ```php $user->userInfo->update(['key', 'value']);``` should work if you've struct the model good.